# Can't display product side by side

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to display products side by side in responsive groups but they a; ways display as lists.
I've tried `float: left` and `display: inline block` but nothing worked. Here is my code:
Js files:
(product file)

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Product.css'

function Product() {
  return (
   <div className='product'> 
    <div className='product_info'> 
     <p>Product #1</p>
     
     <p className='product_price'>
      <small>$</small>
      <strong>1</strong>
     </p>
     
    
     <div className='product_rating'>
      <p>product feedback feature will come soon</p>
     </div>
    </div> 
    <img className='img' src='http://www.thuetruyen.com/image/coffe.jpg' alt='No product yet' />
   
   <button>Add to basket?</button>
   
   </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

(Home file)

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Product from './Product'

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='home'>
     <div className='home_container'>
     <img className='image_uwu' src='http://www.thuetruyen.com/image/coming-soon.jpg' alt='banner'/>
     <div className='home_row'> 
      <Product /> <Product />
     </div>

     <div className='home_row'> 
     
     </div>

     <div className='home_row'> 
     
     </div>

     </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

CSS file:

```css
.product{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img {
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product_info{
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}

.product_rating{
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product > button {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(3, 255, 217);
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Here what's it looks like:
[not good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZQxn.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the JSX in your product component ?

Comment: Done. I mistook the CSS files for the JS one